# Bash redirecting stdin as a standard input

Tags: bash, stdin, file-descriptor, io-redirection

In my script, sometimes I need a script to be passed to SSH, and sometimes let the user interact.

I tried this trick:

```
if [ "" != "$SSH_SCRIPT" ] ; then
  ...
else
  SSH_SCRIPT="&0";
fi
```

And then:

```
ssh $SSH_IGNORE_STDIN $SSH_TTY $noKeyCheck -i $AWS_KEY $USER_@$HOST_ "$COMMAND_SSH" <$SSH_SCRIPT;
```

Which I assumed would work because `cat <&0` works.

But when I use a variable after `<`, it works differently - it complains that file `&0` was not found. Looks like `<&n` is a syntax construct. Reproducible this way:

```
$ FOO='&0';
$ cat <$FOO
bash: &0: No such file or directory
```

**Is there a way to parametrize redirection by file descriptor number?**

Enclosing the whole command to `bash -c "..."` isn't probably a good idea because it makes the whole thing more complicated.
Uploading the command to the remote server and running it there is also a bit overkill.

So far I have resorted to:

```
    if [ "" == "$SSH_SCRIPT" ] ; then
        ssh $SSH_IGNORE_STDIN $SSH_TTY $noKeyCheck -i $AWS_KEY $USER_@$HOST_ "$COMMAND_SSH";
    else
        ssh $SSH_IGNORE_STDIN $SSH_TTY $noKeyCheck -i $AWS_KEY $USER_@$HOST_ "$COMMAND_SSH" <$SSH_SCRIPT;
    fi
```

Comment: The redirection operator in this case is "<&".

Answer (score 2):

`bash` will recognize `/dev/stdin` as the argument to a redirection whether or not your file system exposes such a file.

```
if [ -z "$SSH_SCRIPT" ]; then
    SSH_SCRIPT=/dev/stdin
fi

ssh ... < "$SSH_SCRIPT"
```

Comment: `/dev/fd/0` would also work. Reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections

Comment: Or shorten to `ssh ... < "${SSH_SCRIPT:-/dev/stdin}"`.